# How to add back-end form field parameters in a Joomla Module?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I checked out this article [Creating a simple module/Developing a Basic Module](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1%3aCreating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module) for building a basic Joomla module. I understood the MVC architecture and file structure they've mentioned there. It is a simple Hello World module for Joomla.

Now I want to modify this module in a way that it accepts whatever text I enter (instead of static "Hello World") from Joomla back-end. What I don't get is, **how to** or **where to** enter the code for the text-box field that gets displayed in Joomla back-end of this module?

In short, the link above doesn't mention anything about entering back-end parameters for a module. How to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You define parameters in the XML file like so:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="param1" type="text" default="" label="" description="">
            <field name="param2" type="text" default="" label="" description="">
            <field name="param3" type="text" default="" label="" description="">
            // add more here
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

And you can call them like so:

```
echo $params->get('param1');
echo $params->get('param2');
// and so on
```

Hope this helps

Comment: As an addition to Lodder, the XML is placed in the mod_yourmodule.xml right next to mod_yourmodule.php and you have to zip and install it for the fields to show up.

Comment: My next question would have been to ask for a link that explains in detail about the same. Jobin Jose did just that --> [Tutorial](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-module-development-tutorial)

Comment: This link shows you the types of parameters that can used use: http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_and_parameter_types

Comment: also can we get the params from a specific fieldlist?

Comment: @MadMax - I don't think Joomla supports this. Each parameter should have a unique name which you then calling using `$params->get('NAME');`.

Comment: After adding that field, what's the process to have Joomla! recognize the change and update the database, please? I also updated the version and uploaded the xml. _Extensions > Manage_ doesn't show the version anymore.

Comment: @Andy - please ask any new questions you have over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Inside your module config xml you have to add your module params
like below.

```
<config>
<fields name="params">
<fieldset name="basic">
<field name="face_book_link" type="text" default="" label="Face Book Link " description="Face Book Link" size="60"/>
<field name="face_book_link_yes" type="radio" default="1" label="DisplayFB Link" description="DisplayFB Link">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</field>
</fieldset>
</fields>
</config>
```

a detailed module development [tutorial](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-module-development-tutorial)

Hope its helps..